# Get all except the first one in an array

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to slice an array to create a new array containing all but the first entry in the array.
This is what i tried:

```
@arguments = $splittedCommands[1..-1];
```

Which gives me an empty result.
1 should be the second entry and -1 should be the last, so why doesn't this work?

Comment: The range operator isn't special in array subscripts. `1 .. -1` is empty, because `-1` is smaller than `1`. However, `-1` as an index is interpreted as the last element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest may be to assign it into another list, using

```
( undef, my @commands ) = @splittedCommands;
```

Assigning into `undef` here throws away the first result, then the remainder goes into `@commands`

Another approach could be to assign the lot and then remove the first

```
my @commands = @splittedCommands;
shift @commands;
```

This could also be simplified if you didn't need to keep the original array around any more; just `shift` the first item off `@splittedCommands` then use it directly.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `@` in front of array when slicing an array (`$` tells that your're accessing single scalar value inside array), so

```
my @arguments = @splittedCommands[ 1 .. $#splittedCommands ];
```

Second, your range should be either `-$#splittedCommands .. -1` or `1 .. $#splittedCommands` with later being more common and straightforward.

Comment: `@arguments = @$_[ 1 .. $#$_ ] for \@splittedCommands` is less redundant at the expense of readability.

Comment: this is much harder to understand

Answer (score 1):

If the original array must be left intact then the obvious way seems to be to copy the whole array and remove the first element.

```
shift(my @commands = @splittedCommands)
```

will do just fine